# Python: Extracting information from one dataframe to another (with different lengths) based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2) that differ in length (25696 and 28). Nonetheless, they have two columns that share the same information (date and day_period).

Here's a preview of the data:

```
df1 
>>
    id timestamp                 col1   col2    day_period  date
0    A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.000  12     32      Morning     2021-06-09
1    A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.000  5      32      Morning     2021-06-09
2    A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.587  54     34      Morning     2021-06-09
3    A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.716  56     53      Morning     2021-06-09 
4    A  2021-06-09 08:12:33.000  34     23      Morning     2021-06-09


df2
>>
    date       day_period   temperature atmospheric_pressure    wind_speed  humidity
0   2021-06-09  Night       15          30.1                    2.6         94
1   2021-06-09  Morning     14          30.1                    3.2         90
2   2021-06-09  Day         18          30.1                    4.2         60
3   2021-06-09  Evening     19          30.0                    2.7         66
4   2021-06-10  Night       16          30.0                    3.6         81
```

My goal is to merge all of the other columns of df2 to df1 when day_period and date are the same. In the case of the preview in df1, the values from **df2[["temperature", "atmospheric_pressure", "wind_speed", "humidity"]]** would be repeated for all the observation with the date **2021-06-09** and day_period **Morning**. How can this be achieved considering the difference in length?

So, the output I am aiming is something like this:

```
    id timestamp                 col1   col2    day_period  date        temperature    atmospheric_pressure  wind_speed  humidity
0    A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.000  12     32      Morning     2021-06-09  15             30.1                  2.6           94
1    A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.000  5      32      Morning     2021-06-09  14             30.1                  3.2           90
2    A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.587  54     34      Morning     2021-06-09  18             30.1                  4.2           60
3    A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.716  56     53      Morning     2021-06-09  19             30.0                  2.7           66
4    A  2021-06-09 08:12:33.000  34     23      Morning     2021-06-09  16             30.0                  3.6           81
```

Note that there's an ID columns in df1 so the date is only cronologically ordered per ID.

Comment: I guess merge both df's on `['day_period','date']`

Comment: Could you show what the end result would look like?

Comment: Just edited the question to add the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join, for example using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=['date', 'day_period'], right_on=['date', 'day_period'])
```

output:

```
  id                timestamp  col1  col2 day_period        date  temperature  atmospheric_pressure  wind_speed  humidity
0  A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.000    12    32    Morning  2021-06-09           14                  30.1         3.2        90
1  A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.000     5    32    Morning  2021-06-09           14                  30.1         3.2        90
2  A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.587    54    34    Morning  2021-06-09           14                  30.1         3.2        90
3  A  2021-06-09 08:12:18.716    56    53    Morning  2021-06-09           14                  30.1         3.2        90
4  A  2021-06-09 08:12:33.000    34    23    Morning  2021-06-09           14                  30.1         3.2        90
```